# ng-click not working on infowindow maps marker

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, flux

```
     for (let i of this.latlong) {
            this.customWindow = '<div ng-click="mapSearchController.getRestaurantBranchPage(' + i.restaurantId + ')"><img width="150" height="150" src="client/' + i.restaurantImg + '"/>' + '<b>' + i.restaurantTagline + '</b></div>';
            let customWindow = this.customWindow;
            let marker = [];
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: this.map,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(i.latitude, i.longitude)
            });
            marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
            //let marker = this.marker;
            setTimeout(function() {
                marker.setAnimation(null);
            }, 1500);
            //marker.content = '<div class="infoWindowContent">' + i.restaurantName + '</div>';
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    restoInfoWindow.setContent(customWindow);
                    restoInfoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
            this.markers.push(marker);
        }
```

All the info windows load on marker click but the further ng-click doesnt work on click
ng-click doesnt hit the required angularjs function in the directive.
i have tried using both span and div but the problem remains the same and still no call.
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just

```
this.customWindow = '<div ng-click="mapSearchController.....';
```

you need use $compile service.

```
$compile('<div ng-click="mapSearchController.....')($scope);
```

$scope should be a scope of mapSearchController

Only in that case your ng-click will work properly.

Comment: actually i am using angularjs + flux directive and cannot use $compile as well as $scope in it...

Comment: can you create https://jsfiddle.net example?  It will help to understand what you actually have?